# Check if string is in file, if so, replace that specific line that contains the string

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("What name would you like to be known as?");
string usernameforscore = Console.ReadLine();
int classicscore = 0;
string path = "";
File.AppendAllText(path, (usernameforscore + " " + classicscore + Environment.NewLine));
```

So essentially this will write a name and a score to a file one line after another, I want to add some kind of validation that checks if someone's entered username is in the file, it will then override that entire line with the new username and score data.

"classicsscore" references the score of the user, stored as an integer previously. It is then placed into a text file along with the person's inputting string username i.e. "John 12". What I want is that if a person inputs John as their username, which the score 400, the line would then be replaced with "John 400" and not affect the rest of the text file.

I'm using Visual studio, C# console program.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, couldn't find a specific answer myself.

Comment: What's the nature of classicscore? E.g. are we guaranteed that it doesn't contain any embedded spaces and so guaranteed that we can find and strip it by finding the last space in a line?

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what a classicscore is nor much of what you said. So I'm not going to be able to answer that one. It's a .txt file if that helps.

Comment: @DomBeasley This is a variable in your code. `usernameforscore + " " + classicscore` how you don't know what it can be?

Comment: So usernameforscore is an input, which gives a string, I want to check if that username is already in the file, if it is, I want the line replaced with the username and their score - which is set previously.

Comment: What if someone types `John 9` as a username and there is already a line for user `John` with score `9` (which, according to your code, have a space between them)? Using space as a separator is *never* going to be safe, you need a separator that you can disallow to exist inside the username.

Comment: What is the `type` of classicscore? Is that int? string? something else?

Comment: Ok so, I get it now, classicsscore is an integer that is previously set sorry. If someone were to put John 9 then I can sort that out later and verify that username inputs are just one word strings.

Comment: @PeterB that can easily differencied, because you'll compare `John 9` against `John`. If `John 9` has already a score, you can retrieve easily his name in the line `John 9 42`

Comment: Certainly the best option here is to use a standardized format like JSON or XML, which will solve your edge cases.  And there are very good libraries that will make your life easier.

Comment: I've never used either of those so will need a bit more than that.

Comment: Text files, regardless of content, aren't really designed to be updated. You will need to read in and write out to a new file, then rename / delete as necessary. A database or a binary file would allow you to update in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im thinking something like this should work for you.

```
public void AddOrUpdate(string userName, int score)
{
    string path = "";
    var newLine = userName + " " + score;
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    var wasUpdated = false;
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var foundUserName = line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf(' '));
            if (foundUserName == userName)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(newLine);
                wasUpdated = true;
            }
            else
                writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
        if(!wasUpdated)
            writer.WriteLine(newLine);
    }
}
```

But unless you need this specific format for some reason using a database would be a much better option.

Comment: I guess I can look into databases, never used one before. I'll try and implement this for now, thanks.

Comment: All this seems to be doing is writing the names and scores straight after on another on the same line, not actually replacing anything. I had to add static to make it work so I may have messed it up somehow,

Comment: Yeh, change `writer.Write(line);` to `writer.WriteLine(line);`